# Rails query more than n post per date

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

I have `User` and `Post` models `has_many<=>belongs_to`

i need to find users which more than N post per day

i have done only this query with allows me to find users with more posts than N

```
User.select('users.*, count(posts.id)').joins(:posts).group('posts.id').having('count(posts.id) > 1')
```

How to update my query?

Answer (score 0):

achieved with

```
User.select('users.*, count(posts.id)').joins(:posts).
group('users.id').
having('count(posts.id) >= 1').
where("DATE(posts.created_at) = ?",Date.today)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
User.select('users.*').
joins(:posts).
group('posts.created_at::date').
having('count(posts.id) > 1').
order('posts.created_at::date desc')
```

The difference here, is grouping by day, rather than grouping by post-count.